# Как передать значение переменной из одного скрипта в другой? ("NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object")

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

У меня есть 2 скрипта  `Coin` и `SpawnBombs`.

В скрипте `SpawnBombs` лежит переменная `s`, которая подсчитывает очки, а скрипт `Coin` находиться в объекте `CoinSprite`, при взятии этого объекте (`CoinSprite`) игроком, количество очков должно увеличивать на `5` (то бишь увеличить переменную `s` на `5`).

Объект `CoinSprite` создается в `SpawnBombs`.

Сколько способов я не пробивал одна и та же ошибка

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Coin:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour {
    private float starTime;
    private float coinTime;
    void Start()
    {
       // SpawnBombs sc = GetComponent<SpawnBombs>();
        coinTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
        coinTime = coinTime + 2f;
    }
        void Update()
    {
        starTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
        if (coinTime < starTime)
            Destroy(gameObject);


    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == ("Player"))
        {
            other.GetComponent<SpawnBombs>().s += 5;
            //GameObject.Find("coin").GetComponent<SpawnBombs>();
            Destroy(gameObject);

        }

    }
}
```

SpawnBombs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SpawnBombs : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text score;
    public GameObject bomb;
    public GameObject raket;
    public GameObject coin;
    private float startTime;
    private float coinTime;
    public int s = 0;
    System.Random rand = new System.Random();
    int r=14,c=0;
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(Spawn());

    }
    IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        while (!Player.lose)
        {
            s++;
            Instantiate(bomb, new Vector2(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-3f, 3f), 5.9f),Quaternion.identity);
            if (r==0)
            {
                s++;
                Instantiate(raket, new Vector2(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-3f, 3f), 5.9f), Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -90f));
                r = 2;
            }
            else
             r--;


            c = rand.Next(0, 5);
            if (c == 1)
            {
                Instantiate(coin, new Vector2(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-3f, 3f), -2.5f), Quaternion.identity);
            }


            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {

        string sco = (s).ToString();
        score.text = sco;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Для каких целей вы оборачиваете в скобки `("Player")` при сравнения?

Comment: ну для того чтоб когда мой игрок с Tag (Player) входил в колайдер монетки происходило действие, ну а почему именно скобки, то я в видео уроке видал так делали

Comment: не нужно этого делать.

Comment: ну это все равно не помогает решить проблему с ошибкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил перепробывать все названия в моем проекте и сработало при Main Camera, наверное потому что скрипт SpawnBombs прикреплен к ней

```
GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<SpawnBombs>().s += 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если просто исправить в вашем коде, то вот так попробуйте:

```
public class Coin : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float starTime;
    private float coinTime;
    private SpawnBombs sc; // вот тут объявляете переменную.

    void Start()
    {
        // в старте не надо инициализировать sc, у вас же не понятно компонент какого объекта
        coinTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
        coinTime = coinTime + 2f;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        starTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
        if (coinTime < starTime)
            Destroy(gameObject);


    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == ("Player"))
        {
            sc = other.gameObject.GetComponent<SpawnBombs>(); // даете компонент
            sc.s += 5; // работаете с переменной
```

...
а если хотите сразу в GetComponent, то sc вообще нигде не нужен:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == ("Player"))
    {
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<SpawnBombs>().s += 5;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло, ругаеться на строку:
 sc.s += 5;
с той же ошибкой

Comment: Да, тупанул, gameObject не поставил. Исправил.

Comment: и все равно та же ошибка(

Comment: может я где то натупил с названиями или метками (Tag)? Или они тут роли не играют?

Comment: я бы вообще использовал      if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("TagPlayer")) {  }, а если вы строку other.gameObject.GetComponent<SpawnBombs>().s += 5; закоментите, то строка  Destroy(gameObject); срабатывает без ошибок?

Comment: Да, без ошибки, объект пропадает как только игрок попадает в его колайдер

Comment: Больше нету идей как решить эту проблему?